# UICollectionView not being populated by NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, populate

Afternoon all,

A few weeks back I looked in to UICollectionView's, and how they function. I feel they'd be the best option for me for the project I'm in the early stages of developing.

Now in the past I've been able to establish the view, populating it from a static list of strings I establish on the viewDidLoad method which are used to get the name of an image. However, I'm now using the MutableArray to store UIImage's themselves, but unfortunately I don't seem to be able to populate the table.

```
[super viewDidLoad];

imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlankBloop.png"]];
```

Now since i'm using the image itself, rather than a simple string, I had to edit the cellForItemAtIndexPath method to grab the object itself

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:100];

cellImageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell; }
```

The Cell is correctly labeled as "Cell", as well as having a UIImageView with the tag of 100, however as mentioned about, I can't seem to populate the view.

It's most likely a small error on my part, with me having to move from a previous method, and if so, so be it, it's part of the learning process.

Either way, I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could shine a light on the situation.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you logged [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] to see if it's returning an image?

Comment: @rdelmar Well for starters I was quite the fool and forgot to assign the dataSource and delegate, so it wasn't actually performing anything.

However, it seems that the setImage method is returning the error..

"unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d42600"